# show_admin_bar_front => false doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm inserting a user with **'show_admin_bar_front' => false**. When I login, the admin bar is still there. Can someone tell me why?

```
$user = wp_insert_user( array (
        'user_login' =>  crb_get_nicname( $_POST['first_name'], 
$_POST['last_name'] ),
        'user_email' =>  $_POST['email'],
        'user_pass' =>  $_POST['password'],
        'first_name' =>  $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name' =>  $_POST['last_name'],
        'role' =>  $_POST['role'],
        'show_admin_bar_front' => false
    ) );
```

Comment: Is the role of the user is `administrator`?

Comment: which version of WP are you using?

Comment: No, it is not. It si custom role.

Comment: I;m using the last version of WP

Comment: please try "false" instead of false (so as a string)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works

Comment: you're welcome. Added this as answer as well, in case this question will raise more often, which I could see in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though I can't tell you why exactly that is, I can tell you, that you have to use a `string`, instead of a `boolean`. The docs seems to be wrong on that option.

```
$user = wp_insert_user( array (
        'user_login' =>  crb_get_nicname( $_POST['first_name'], 
$_POST['last_name'] ),
        'user_email' =>  $_POST['email'],
        'user_pass' =>  $_POST['password'],
        'first_name' =>  $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name' =>  $_POST['last_name'],
        'role' =>  $_POST['role'],
        'show_admin_bar_front' => "false" // <-- now as string
    ));
```

As said before, the docs state:

> **show_admin_bar_front**
>
> *(string|bool)* Whether to display the Admin Bar for the user on the site's front end. Default true.

But bool simply isn't accepted here.

Comment: I just adding the same answer but +1 you made it !